Was the UNSC resolution that "called upon" Iran to not develop/test missiles also non-binding?
AP:

Tehran also says it hasn’t violated a U.N. resolution on its ballistic missile program as it only “called upon” Iran not to conduct such tests.

Recently I discovered that there are non-binding UNSC resolutions. Was this resolution calling upon Iran to not develop/test missiles also non-binding, according to the various P5 members (and the details of the resolution, e.g. was it explicitly a Chapter VII one)?

See my comment on the linked question.  There is no such thing as a "non-binding" nor a "binding" resolution.  This is simply not a proper way to categorise resolutions.  There are resolutions that authorise force, there are resolutions that don't.    But sovereign countries cannot be "bound"
